# How to create bundle product programatically and add it to cart at runtime?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, bundled-product

I want to create a bundle product with radio and checkboxes at run time and add it to cart.Suggest me solution

Comment: What do you mean by run time?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri  on button click create the bundle product and the phtml selected product must be added as items (radio or check boxes)with qty in bundle product and add the bundle product to cart